# How to set the exchange for MultiBit Wallet Currency Ticker?

Tags: multibit

How can I set which exchange is used to feed the currency ticker in MultiBit, i.e. get rid of Mt. Gox and put MarketCap or some other legitimate exchange in its place?

Comment: Could you give us more detail on where you want to change the currency ticker? It took me a long time to realize you're asking about the ticker in the Multibit wallet, I thought you were referring to bitcoinity or something.

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in your preferences:

[image]